# Scopus500Error: Error calling Solr Search Service

Tags: pybliometrics

when I used pybliometrics to get the co_authors, sometimes I get this error, but sometimes not
I want to know why and how to solve it.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "G:\dissertationdatabase\iteration3\iteration3.py", line 16, in <module>
    coauthors = pd.DataFrame(au.get_coauthors())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\author_retrieval.py", line 289, in get_coauthors
    res = get_content(url, api="AuthorSearch")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\utils\get_content.py", line 97, in get_content
    raise errors[resp.status_code](reason)

Scopus500Error: Error calling Solr Search Service
```

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow! Please provide a minimal working example, i.e. code that others can copy right away, the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Errors in the 5xx area are due to server errors. My feeling is that they're often idiosyncratic. Only Elsevier can tell what's really happening.

Answer (score 0):

If this has worked previously, but is not working now, my suggestion would be to retry to see if this was a temporary issue.

If the problem persists, please contact Elsevier Support:

https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/researchproductsapis/